# localstorage on chrome extension

Tags: api, google-chrome, storage

How I store date on chrome. I tried localstorage but stupid reason they won't it allow. I tied cookies but no. Is away store any data at all. I tried chrome.storage but that not defined. How do I fix this?

Comment: what is wrong in using local storage ? . what do you wanna store Key Value pair or Sqlite database ?

Comment: You can use localStorage in an extension.. How are you setting the data in local storage?

Comment: I did understand how localStorage worked on chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friend you need to share code also . If i understood your question clearly you should go like this

```
  var car = {};
    car.wheels = 4;
    car.doors = 2;
    car.sound = 'vroom';
    car.name = 'Lightning McQueen';
    console.log( car );
    localStorage.setItem( 'car', car );
    console.log( JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'car' ) ) );
```

This is how local storage get use . If still problem is there use window.localStorage.setItem and window.localStorage.getItem

Comment: Though you can store objects in localstorage but you can't pull it out.. You have to stringify it first during the set and the do a JSON.parse(localStorage.get('car')) while pulling it out..

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `chrome.storage` with your extension. I can't tell you what you're doing wrong without seeing your code, but make sure you have the permission set correctly in your manifest:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
   ...
  "permissions": [
  "storage"
],
...
}
```

Please provide an example of how you're trying to access `chrome.storage` and `localStorage`.